# Delete Hidden Partitions After Removing Windows from a Mac

Tags: windows-8, mac, hard-drive, partitioning, macbook-pro

I am dual-booting my mid-2012 MacBook Pro into windows 8. Recently, however, I had to delete the windows partition because windows wasn't working. Now I am trying to put windows back on, but when I run `ls /dev/disk*` in terminal it shows `/dev/disk0 /dev/disk0s1 /dev/disk0s2 /dev/disk0s3`, which means that for some reason there is still two "ghost"/hidden windows partitions (disk0s3 & disk0s4) on my Hard Drive. And because windows only works on HDs with four partitions or less, I am unable to reinstall it. Also, the first time I restarted after deleting the windows partition, I got a black windows command prompt screen saying "missing operating system", so I'm pretty sure that my old win8 installation is behind this.

So how do I remove the old windows partitions to make room for the new one?

Comment: Did you create and/or remove the partitions via Boot Camp Assistant or manually?

Comment: Using Boot Camp Assistant

Comment: Can you include the output of `diskutil list` in the question? Two of the partitions are probably just the Recovery HD and EFI partitions. You can show hidden partitions in Disk Utility by running `defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled -bool true` and selecting Debug > Show every partition.